What does "that" as a relative pronoun here refer to
In Eysenck's fundamentals of psychology,

Hard determinism: the notion that all of our actions are totally determined by a combination of causes; see soft determinism. Soft determinism: the notion that all behavior has a cause, but some forms of behavior are more constrained by the current situation than are others.
Many (probably most) psychologists favor soft determinism by William James. According to this position, it is accepted that all human actions have a cause. However, it is assumed that there is a valid distinction between behavior highly constrained by the situation (that appears involuntary) and behavior only modestly constrained by the situation (that appears voluntary). For example, a child may apologize for swearing because he/she will be punished if an apology isn’t forthcoming (highly constrained behavior) or because he/she is genuinely upset at causing offence (modestly constrained behavior). The underlying causes are more obvious when behavior is highly constrained by situational forces.

What does "that" in "that appears involuntary " and "that appears voluntary " refer to? Or which noun phrases do the relative clauses modify?
If "that" refers to "situation", What does it mean by a situation appearing voluntary and involuntary here?

I. Relative pronoun "that".
OP has asked

What does "that" in "that appears involuntary" and "that appears voluntary " refer to?
Or which noun phrases do the relative clauses modify?

In the first sentence the relative clause in brackets (that appears involuntary) is modifying the noun phrase -  "behavior highly constrained by the situation" and the relative pronoun "that" refers to the entire noun phrase it modifies (highly constrained behavior)
Similarly in the second sentence, the relative clause in brackets (that appears voluntary) modifies the noun phrase - "behavior only modestly constrained by the situation" and the relative pronoun "that" refers to the entire noun phrase it modifies (modestly constrained behavior).
II. that doesn't refer to "situation":.

If "that" refers to "situation", What does it mean by a situation appearing voluntary and involuntary here?

As explained it is the "behavior highly constrained by the situation" is involuntary
and the "behavior only modestly constrained by the situation" is voluntary.

In behavior highly constrained by the situation that appears involuntary, the relativiser that  has antecedent behavior highly constrained by the situation.
The same applies to the other case.
The adjectives involuntary and voluntary describe the behaviors.

thanks. how do you know the relative clause doesn't modify the nearest noun phrase "situation" but the farther one "behavior"?

@Tim,  situation appears voluntary or involuntary wouldn't make sense.

@Tim On a syntax-parsing level, you don't know that difference, since "situation that appears involuntary" is not an impossibility, clunky, yes, but not impossible. On a semantic level, you can figure it out by looking above at "some forms of behavior are more constrained by the current situation" and realizing that the phrase "behavior highly constrained by the situation" and "behavior that appears involuntary" are quite synonymous.
